# Producing iOS visual assets from Storyboard using point to pixel conversions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uistoryboard, retina-display

I'm currently designing an interface using Xcode storyboard and Compact Size class. One of the main problem I'm facing is instructing the graphic designer about the size in pixels of the visual assets required. I'm reading a lot of documentation about it (like [this](http://click-labs.com/ios-8-design-cheat-sheet-and-free-iphone6plus-gui-psd/) or [this](http://www.kinvey.com/blog/2765/ios-and-android-design-guidelines-cheat-sheet))
but I still find it a bit confusing. For example let's take in consideration this simple design that I want to run on different iPhone screens:

[image]

the reported size of the UIImageView is 400 pt x 356 pt:

[image]

Now, I should create an Image Asset in my Assets Catalog with 4 different resolutions (iPhone):

[image]

**Question 1)**: are the following resolutions correct?

- image.png 400x356pixels (normal)
- image@2x.png 800x712 (retina)
- image@3x.png 1200x1068 (retina-HD)

I don't see any resolution matching with the following specifications:

[image]

**Question 2)**: How's Retina 4 2x different from just 2x?

**Question 3)**: How does it work when instead of the compact class we use a generic class (namely Any-Any)? Is the same operation of taking the dimension in pt and perfoming x1,x2 and x3 correct?

Comment: http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions

Comment: thanks for the comment but that doesn't answer my question. The simple multiplication doesn't seem to be the solution.Good link thou